# How to set one Processor is triggered by more than one incoming FlowFile from different connection in Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

My plan is that `M part` will not execute until `P1 and P2 parts` complete,because `P1/P2 part` would insert data into Parent tables,and `M part` would insert data into Child table.

[image]

P1/P2 part:`GenerateFlowFile->PutSql`

M part:`ExecuteSql(triggered by event)-PutDatebaseRecord`

I’ve tried to use `funnel` was connected by `P1 and P2 parts`,and then `M part` which triggered by event was connected by `funnel`.However,`M part` would be triggered by one of `the P1 and P2 parts`,not **by a whole**.

**How can I make the `ExecuteSql` Processor will not to execute until all Processor of P1 and P2 parts complete?**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: separate a flowfile before p processors and merge it after p processors. then trigger m.

Comment: @Lamanus I've did this before,but `MergeContent`  is recommended that the Processor be configured with only a single incoming connection, as Group of FlowFiles will not be created from FlowFiles in different connections.Any suggestion?TIA

Comment: You may force to use a single flowfile at the beginning but if you have any reason that cannot use, then I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wait, notify and funnel processors before M, like this

```
P1 -> Notify -> Funnel F -> M

P2 -> Notify -> Funnel F -> M

Funnel -> Wait (Signal Count == 2)
```